# compiler error when trying to use addEventListener via interface

Tags: actionscript-3

Trying to use addEventlistener with an interface, but i get a compiler error : 
=> Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type IScene.

```
//IScene.as 

    public interface IScene 
        {

            function show():void

            function load():void;

            function unload():void;
        }
```

---

```
//Main.as
                    var scene:IScene  ;

        scene= sceneView_Arr[scene_number] ;


        scene.addEventListener( GameEvent.ON_LOAD_SCENE , start );
        scene.load();
        scene.show();
```

How should i achieve it then ?

Comment: (scene as IEventDispatcher).addEventListener( GameEvent.ON_LOAD_SCENE , start );

Comment: IScene may not be extending IEventDispatcher, then you will have a null casting result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Fox in socks answer, I would recommend a slightly different approach:

```
public interface IScene extends IEventDispatcher
```

And then for your actual scene classes

```
public class MyScene extends EventDispatcher implements IScene
```

And then you can use it as you already have, without any additional code.

```
scene.addEventListener(GameEvent.ON_LOAD_SCENE, start);
```

Comment: but in this case, scene MUST  be MyScene type!

Comment: ...no? Whatever type Scene is, so long as it extends EventDispatcher it satisfies the new requirements for implementing IScene *with* IEventDispatcher and you're fine.